# How to change image source with jQuery and load it with some nice effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have am image on my page and i am changing its image source with java script.
All I need is to change this image with some beautiful sliding effect. 
What I want is when i click on a button to change the image, the first image should disappear and another one should show in some some decent way (not like a jerk or blink)

Comment: You forgot to post your code...

Comment: Thanks for replying ... I am just changing Image source on buttonclick event by calling this function all I need noe to put some sliding effect when this image changes (when I change its source)
function changeimage(ID) {
if (ID == 'first') {
      $('#imgmain').attr('src', '../siteimages/digitalsignature_slide1.JPG');}

Answer (score 1):

You can put second image behind the first one, and then make fadeout() efect on the first image.

Comment: You could improve this answer by providing an example.

Comment: Code was too long to put it in comment. So i write it down in new answer.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

$(".firstimage_classname").fadeout();
$(".secondimage_classname").fadeIn();

you can give time interval as well.

otherwise try

$(".firstimage_classname").slideUp();
$(".secondimage_classname").fadeIn();

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
 $(".YourClassSelector").fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000, function () {
        var $next = $(this).attr('src','http://abc.com/logo.png');

    });
```

Hope it would helps you.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Here you go example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Srtict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/tr/xhtml1/dtd/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pl" lang="pl">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .front{
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                position: absolute;
                left: 10px;
                top: 10px;
                z-index: 10;
            }

            .back{
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                position: absolute;
                left: 10px;
                top: 10px;
                z-index: 1;
            }
        </style>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_lte6.css" /> <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <img src="1.jpg" class="front" />
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('.front').click(function(){
                    $('#content').append('<img src="2.jpg" class="back" />');
                    $(this).fadeOut(500, function(){
                        $('.front').remove();
                        $('.back').addClass('front').removeClass('back');
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```